# Import error in Python: Polygon

Tags: python, polygon, importerror

I installed this library called Polygon, in Python 2.7.3. But, each time I import it I get the next error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Polygon/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
   from Polygon.cPolygon import *
ImportError: No module named cPolygon
```

I have no idea about what could be going wrong. And also, I have already tried to contact the original author of this on his [personal webpage](http://www.j-raedler.de/projects/polygon/).

but he hasn't replied though  :(   I wonder if someone can help me with this issue please.

Comment: How did you install the library? It appears to have a C extension that is missing.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the [`doc/Polygon.txt`](https://github.com/jraedler/Polygon2/blob/master/doc/Polygon.txt) documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you *didn't* in fact install it, but instead just copied it to your working directory. As always, [run `setup.py` with the appropriate arguments to install](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if you try to run python from inside the directory you used to install Polygon. Move to a different directory and try again.